# Can addresses used in a single tx be assumed to be from the same wallet?

Tags: transactions, address, transaction-input

## can addresses of input of a single tx be always considered as belonging to same account?

[image: sample transaction]

Above is a sample transaction on bitcoin.
Here, input addresses are

```
3P2hJg8iRSBExAjd9yQGaazCLPFLeGB3hU (0.88970519 BTC - Output)
35jRUYxAwkqFhGyiGvS6Q4Aqxgcru7m9DM (0.43636859 BTC - Output)
```

My question is, since these two addresses are in a single tx, can they be considered as coming from same account (or wallet)?

The reason why I ask is I want to extract account-like info because bitcoin world actually has no account concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot assume this.

There are a number of ways in which individual inputs may belong to different wallets/owners. For example:

- They could come from a hosted wallet or exchange, where inputs may span coins deposited by thousands of individual users, and selected for a transaction with no particular relation to the user making that transaction
- Coinjoin techniques allow multiple individual transactions from any number of actors to be combined into a single large transaction, mixing all of the individual inputs and outputs

Answer (score 0):

That was assumption mentioned in Bitcoin whitepaper by Satoshi Nakamoto, but, as mentioned above, is not true.